# cannot create table: SQL Error: ORA-00600

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

getting

```
SQL Error: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4097], [23], [10], [24005], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

when try to create table

```
  CREATE TABLE"LIR" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "US" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EXCUTE" NUMBER, 
    "DOV" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EOV" DATE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "AMA" ;
```

Comment: [My Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com) has a look-up tool for ORA-600 errors (see doc ID 153788.1) and a troubleshooting tool (see doc ID 1521912.1). Depending on your exact version there may be a hit for this related to transportable tablespaces and securefile LOBs. You should probably raise a service request with Oracle to investigate further.

Comment: Why all these parameters? Try it with just the tablespace parameter to see if it works.